# Consistent names for [rainbow-six]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

The tags for *Tom Clancy's Rainbow Six* games use a mix of `rainbow-six` and `rainbow-6`.

- [rainbow-six](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rainbow-six)
- [rainbow-six-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rainbow-six-3)
- [rainbow-6-siege](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rainbow-6-siege)
- [rainbow-6-vegas-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rainbow-6-vegas-2)

I propose renaming these tags to `rainbow-six` for consistency, as it matches the game tiles.

- [rainbow-6-siege](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rainbow-6-siege) -> [rainbow-six-siege](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rainbow-six-siege)
- [rainbow-6-vegas-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rainbow-6-vegas-2) -> [rainbow-six-vegas-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rainbow-six-vegas-2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changed the "6" to "six" for the specified tags and made the previous tags synonyms

Comment: Beat me to it. I also added number '6' variants as synonyms to the first two tags for searchability

Comment: @Robotnik working on getting that status complete badge ;) need more votes!

Comment: [Good luck, we're all counting on you ](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bstatus-completed%5d%20answers%3a0%20duplicate%3ano&searchOn=3)